# Get COUNTof a many-to-one of many-to-one relationship, limit the queryset in django

Tags: django-models, prefetch

Suppose I have 3 models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='categories')
    name = models.CharField()

class Feedback(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='feedbacks')
    content = models.CharField()
```

How can I get total feedback count on every category, and get 3 first products of it too?
I want to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
Category.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('categories', queryset=Product.objects.all().annotate(
        feedback_count=Count('feedbacks')
    )[:3])
).annotate(
    product_count=Count('products'),
    total_feedback_count=Count('categories__feedback_count')
)
```

Please help me, thanks ^^